# Find the last character of a string that got whitespaces after it

Tags: c#, regex, string

This might sound stupid but how can i find the last characters index in a string if the string  looks like this `"string with white-space after last character    "`, if it was consistent and just 1 it would be no problem but sometimes it might be 2 or 3 white-spaces

**EDIT:**
I cant trim my current string to a new string, because the index of the last character wont be right. I want to keep the string as is

This is why and what I got

```
string description = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting indu. Lorem Ipsum has ben indusry s tandard dummy text ever since the 1500s.";
description = Regex.Replace(description, @"(?></?\w+)(?>(?:[^>'""]+|'[^']*'|""[^""]*"")*)>", String.Empty);
if (description.Count() > 101)
{
    description = description.Substring(0, 101);
    if (description.GetLast() != " ")
    {                    
        description = description.Substring(0, description.LastIndexOf(" ", 101)) + "...";
    }
    else
    {
        //here is should find the last character no mather how many whitespaces
        description = description.Substring(0, description.Length - 1) + "...";
    }
}
```

Comment: you say you can't trim the string - are you aware that Trim() doesn't actually modify the original string but returns a new one?

Comment: well, you have more problems here. if you end up with string that contains no spaces (or tabs) you will end up with LastIndexOf(" ") returning -1 and crashing.

TrimEnd() as people suggest and check for -1 if using LastIndexOf();

Comment: What is a problem in first place? You want first 100 characters without braking apart last word?

Comment: I need to get 101 characters and they need to be written like it is. so.. "string might look like this, there is like 5 whitespaces after this     ", i cant trim and get a description looking like "stringmightlooklikethis". I handle the issue of not breaking in a word, but sometimes is just more then 1 whitespace after the last character

Comment: downvote for what? its a legit question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Under the assumption that it doesn't matter that other [whitespace characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) (e.g. tab or line feed) at the end are also ignored, simply use trim:

```
String s = "string with whitespace after last character  ";
int lastChar = s.TrimEnd().Length-1;
```

Note that the original string `s` remains unchanged by that (see [TrimEnd() documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx)).

Comment: worked even when i had whitespace in the begining of the string. Except the -1. For me it was just find with `s.TrimEnd();`

Comment: @Maciej: Yes, thanks for the hint, my original solution didn't work for leading spaces, now with TrimEnd it does. I would upvote your answer but it has the same problem ;)

Comment: I would be interested in the reason for the downvote... is there anything wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 2):

For completeness here is a solution that uses regular expressions (I'm not claiming that it is any better than the other proposed solutions though):

```
var text = "string with whitespace after last character  ";
var regex = new Regex(@"\s*$");
var match = regex.Match(text);
var lastIndex = match.Index - 1;
```

Note that if the string is empty `lastIndex` will be -1 and you need to handle this in your code.

Answer (score 1):

All answers here are **trim** the string so create a new string with **shifted** indices, so the final result would be **wrong** index in the *original* string.

What would be done instead, is just

```
"string with whitespace after last character ".ToCharArray().
          Select((x,i)=> new {x,i}).Where(ch=>ch.x != ' ').Last();
```

returns:

```
x :    'r'
index: 42
```

Comment: That (i.e. "all answers here are trim ... so the final result would be wrong index") only applies if there are spaces in the beginning of the string *as well* as at the end. OP doesn't specify if there can be, but at least Alex explicitly mentions that precondition in his answer; and TrimEnd as used by AndrewR doesn't have the problem you describe at all.

Comment: @nyarlathotep: look on the example provided by OP, it **has** space at the end.

Comment: at the end, yes, but why should there be a wrong index then after trim? the trimmed string contains the original string *without the spaces at the end*, therefore the length of the trimmed string-1 **is** the index of the last character in the orignal string!

Comment: @nyarlathotep: if the space at the end, it would not have effect, but if the space in front of the string, it will.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        string s = "string with whitespace after last character    ";
        int index = s.Length - s
            .ToCharArray()
            .Reverse()
            .TakeWhile(c => c == ' ')
            .Count();
```

Comment: You do not need `.ToCharArray()` because you can use Linq directly on the string `s` (`string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`).

Answer (score 0):

If the string doesn't have any whitespace before the first character, `yourString.Trim().Length -1` should acomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the trim function and get the last index of that string..

Answer (score 0):

why not trim your string

```
string abc = "string with whitespace after last character ";
abc = abc.trim();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one?

```
String s = "string with whitespace after last character  ";
int lastCharIndex = s.Length - (s.TrimEnd().Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just this. No necessity for Linq or Regex. But `TrimEnd()`, not `Trim()`, and you don't need to think whether you have whitespaces in the beginning of the string.

```
string s = "string with whitespace after last character  ";
int lastCharIndex = s.TrimEnd().Length - 1;
```

If OP really wants to use Regex for that, than here's my improvisation:

```
        string text = "string with whitespace after last character  ";
        Match m = Regex.Match(text, @"^(.*)(\w{1})\s*$");
        if (m.Success)
        {
            int index = m.Groups[1].Length;
            Console.WriteLine(text[index]);
            Console.WriteLine(index);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.FindLastIndex` for search last char who not equialent as whitespace:

`Array.FindLastIndex(str.ToCharArray(), ch => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(ch))`